# link to a certain place in a locally hosted website 127.0.0.1:5500

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

This is an update to [link to a place in a locally-hosted website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807449/link-to-a-place-in-a-locally-hosted-website)

I tried the solution:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/#projects"><button
onmouseover="onbutton(this)" onmouseout="offbutton(this)"
type="button">Projects</button></a>
```

while it does change the link in my browser from `127.0.0.1:5500` to `127.0.0.1:5500/#projects`, it does not take me directly to the div tagged with id `#project`- it just leaves me at my current place on the website. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you look at the answer on the page? Seems to work...

Comment: @JASFramework I did, on my end it does not work though. Is the solution not what I have above (with some js code) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, as observation, this is not a CSS question. Here we go.

When you use an anchor with the ID attribute, you dont need to use the entire URL. just the `#id`